# Rolling count of IDs over time frame with condition

Tags: sas

I have a data set like the following:

```
 data work.have;
    input ID mydate date9. type;
    format mydate date9.;
    datalines;
1 11NOV2020 1
1 22OCT2020 1
1 24SEP2020 0
1 26SEP2019 1
2 13OCT2021 1
2 11SEP2020 1
;
run;
```

- I want to count the amount of times an ID has appeared in the last 12 months starting from the mydate variable, by ID.
- The count should start at 0.
- It should only increase the count by 1 if there are any observations in the last 12 months, and those observations have type = 1

The result I want should look something like this:

```
ID    mydate        type    Count
1     11NOV2020     1       1
1     22OCT2020     1       0
1     24SEP2020     0       1
1     26SEP2019     1       0
2     13OCT2021     1       0
2     11SEP2020     1       0
```

For example ID = 1 on the first row gets a count = 1 because it only has one observation the last 12 months where type = 1.

So far I have tried merging the table on itself like the below but it does not produce the correct result.

```
proc sql;
    create table work.want
        as select
         t1.ID
        ,t1.mydate
        ,max(count(t2.id)-1,0) as Count
            from work.have as t1
            left join
            work.have as t2
            on t1.id = t2.id and 0 <= intck('month', t2.mydate, t1.mydate) <= 12 and t2.Type = 1
                group by 1,2
                    order by 1,2 desc;
Quit;
```

I would gladly appreciate an answer in either proc sql or as a data step.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: "... in the last 12 months, by ID." In the last 12 months from today? Or the last 12 months since the ID qualified with type=1?

Comment: The last 12 months based on the mydate on each row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
 data work.have;
    input ID mydate date9. type;
    format mydate date9.;
    datalines;
1 11NOV2020 1
1 22OCT2020 1
1 24SEP2020 0
1 26SEP2019 1
2 13OCT2021 1
2 11SEP2020 1
;
run;

proc sql;
   create table want as
   select *, 
           (select n(type) from have
               where id = a.id
                 and intnx('year', a.mydate, -1, 's') <= mydate < a.mydate
                 and type = 1
           ) as count
   from have as a;
quit;
```

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is this, I believe it will do what you need.

```
*sort from low to high date within ID;
proc sort data=work.have;
    by ID  mydate;
run;

*use "first." method to calc flags u want;
*Assuming no duplicate date rows per ID;
data outdset;
    set work.have;
    by ID;

    retain count ;
    array dates{100};  *However many dates you may have;

    if first.ID then do;
        indx = 1;
        count = 0;
        dates{indx} = mydate;
    end;
    else do;
        indx + 1;
        dates{indx} = mydate;

/*      if mydate ne dates{indx-1} then dates{indx} = mydate; *in case duplicate date rows per ID - handle better;*/

        if type=1 then do x=1 to indx-1 until (mydate - dates{x} >366 );  *loop until seeing dates more than a year ago;
            if intck('year', dates{x}, mydate, 'c') = 0 then count +1; * add 1 if mydate is <1yr after any date before;
        end;
    end;

    output;

    drop indx  dates: ;
run;
```

I've not run it on SAS so let me know if it does the trick.